# Check if any node contains expected value using querySelectorAll

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm using Karma/Jasmine to test that a `ul` on my Angular page contains the text I want. Since it is a `ul` I'm not concerned about the order. Right now I seem to need to specify which node of the result from `querySelectorAll` to check, but that makes fora. more brittle test. Is there a way to check that *any* node in the results matches my expectations.

What I have

```
expect(compiled.querySelectorAll('div.layer-switcher li.layer label')[0].textContent).toContain('Rivers');
```

What I'd like have

```
expect(compiled.querySelectorAll('div.layer-switcher li.layer label').textContents).toContain('Rivers');
```

What I don't want

```
A manual loop through all results and if we fall out the bottom of the loop without finding it then fail test
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you can check for the contents of parent `ul` element instead of `li` elements.

For eg :

```
expect(compiled.querySelectorAll('div.layer-switcher ul').textContent).toContain('Rivers');
```